# Call Webmethod to Fill DropDownList

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asmx, webmethod

I want to fill the DropDownList via SqlQuery in webmethod. But it gives internal Server error.
Except for the error, can't I just do this in javascript?

```
function doldur() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "UserServis.asmx/ListDoldur",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ 'sysName': 'Sudio', 'categoryID': " + 544 + " }",
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d;
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (requeset, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static List<string> ListDoldur()
    {
        List<string> retList = new List<string>();
        SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnLEO"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select BolumAdi from emre_bolumler ", baglanti);
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;
        DataTable dt;
        baglanti.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(komut);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds,"TestTable");
        dt = ds.Tables["TestTable"];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            retList.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        }
        return retList;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

- you are sending data to the code behind method but it does not have a parameter to accept data;
- I think the simplest way is to serialize your datatable and return a JSON string, not a `List<string>` (maybe you can do `return retList.ToArray()` ? not sure);
- skip the dataset, just use a table. I'm not entirely sure what's going on with the loop, but I think when you serialize the data you won't have to do that (unless you have a ton of columns to avoid).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// convert datatable to a string.
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tbl);
```

- when the data is returned to the ajax method, create the dropdown options.